# If Condition Maui Xaml Without Triggers

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-maui

Is it possible to implement an **if condition statement** in **dotnet maui** on xaml page without [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers) .

At least in my experience I find them tedious or not very simple to implement in case (for example) i need to check if a string lenght it's between 5 or 10 characters. I know that xamarin forms lead with the same issue. But doesn't find any simple way to make this. Is there any library or something that i missed out that simplify this problem.

I know that blazor work's different but would like to implement if contidion like this:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    @if (item.lenght > 5)
    {
        <Label  Text="Lenght should be higher than 5" />
    }
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

All info / Code samples / Enhancement / Discussions / Recommendations, they are welcome, I see that it is a very normal topic and of which there are not so many examples

Comment: Conditional compilation is not a thing for XAML

Comment: hi @FreakyAli since you have been in technology for longer than me, why this is not a thing for xaml. And should i mix xaml code with code behind conditionals on xaml.cs file? what are the best practices to replicate a conditional(c#) in xaml?

Comment: Well so the reason there is no conditional compilation in XAML is because its a UI lang and does not need to have CC, UI lang are usually just available for designing purposes. When you need to add conditional compilation or some kind of validation or so on and so forth, You use Converters, Behaviors, Control Templates and so on. There is no issue in using .cs part of the code for UI changes the only problem you might face there is adding binding becomes a bit complex if you are new... If you have a query on how to do a certain thing while designing your UI googling your query helps a lot :)

Comment: Oh yeah, when using .xaml.cs for design make sure you don't add business logic into a View, Cause that defeats the purpose of MVVM. Otherwise using it to define UI elements is 100% ok!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can set an `IsVisible` property on Label with binding a parameter like this:

```
<Label IsVisible="{Binding LabelLength}" Text="Lenght should be higher than 5"></Label>
```

Then you create a method in your viewmodel to realize the `LabelLength`.

```
 public bool LabelLength(String item)
        {
            return item != null && item.Length >= 5;
        }
```

This can check the item whether the length is bigger than 5.

Comment: How can you pass "String item" to LabelLength?

Comment: You can create `String item` in the `viewmodel` then you can pass the item to the LabelLength, and bind it to the label like this: `Text="{Binding item}"`

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the text to the `Visibility` property of the Label and then use a converter (s. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters), to convert the text to a boolean value indicating, that the text is **too short**.